# Prevent timeout when downloading file from Shiny app based on open version of shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, timeout, shiny-server

I've created app that among other things, creates screenshots of provided urls with added custom watermarks.

On local version everything works great. When put on shiny server it works ok...until too many urls are provided at once. App does not freeze and files for download are created on VM on which shiny server functions but download just doesn't happen.

Based on my research I tried to modify shiny-server.conf file with adding `http_keepalive_timeout 50000;`
as seen below:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;
http_keepalive_timeout 50000;
# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

I tried setting it to 0 and putting it in other lines. Is this option avaible to PRO version only or is it working properly and problems with download lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I cannot test anything but you could try increasing the value of `app_idle_timeout` (see http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#application-timeouts).

I know with one of my apps it seemed that generating the download file should be done separately to creating the download file as this would decrease the idle time. I hope that helps but otherwise please provide a reproducible example for me to test as I have some experience with the open and pro versions of shiny server.